# ¿Cómo consumir una API con usuario y contraseña usando php?

Tags: php, api, webservice, aplicación-web, curl

Estoy desarrollando una web para una empresa, de manera interna estamos tratando de desarrollar un pequeño sistema de reservas (Soy un poco nuevo en esto). La información para las reservas la consumo desde una API externa en la cual me otorgaron un usuario y contraseña también... pero no logro obtener los datos. Estoy utilizando el método `cURL` para hacer el consumo del servicio y solo me sale un error `404 url not fund`. No estoy seguro si estoy haciendo algo mal en el código o el problema es directamente con el proveedor. Este es mi código:

```php
require_once "credenciales.php";

/* URL DE API's */

$url = 'https://api.hyperguest.com/hg-apitude/hotel-api/1.0/hotels/';
$url0 = 'https://api.hyperguest.com/hg-apitude/hotel-api/1.0/checkrates/';
$url1 = 'https://api.hyperguest.com/hg-apitude/hotel-api/1.0/bookings/';
$url2 = 'https://api.hyperguest.com/hg-apitude/hotel-content-api/1.0/';
$host = 'https://api.hyperguest.com';

$payload = json_encode($my_user);


/* Ingresamos la url de la api o servicio a consumir */
$curl = curl_init($url0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
/* Autorizamos enviar datos */
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

/* convertimos los datos en el formato solicitado normalmente json */
$payload = json_encode($my_user);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

/* Archivo para guardar datos de sesion */
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  __DIR__ . '/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

/* Ejecutamos petición */
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


if ($err) {
  echo $err;
} else {
  echo $result;
}
```

La respuesta es la siguiente:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "SN.404",
    "message": "Url not found"
  }
}
```

De ante mano, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Es difícil dar una respuesta clara a una pregunta sobre un servicio cerrado y sin documentación abierta. Por ejemplo... de qué forma pide la identificación: Si por CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, por CURLOPT_USERPWD, etc. Además, la `$url0` directa (sin autorización o identificación) da un error y la `$url1` por ejemplo da otro.

Comment: Me comunique con ellos por que, después de unas modificaciones, me da como respuesta `Autorización Invalida`. Su área de soporte me pide los encabezados de las solicitudes HTTP pero cuando les envío el código implementado, me dicen que no logran observar eso que necesitan.

Comment: Pues entonces ya estamos en un caso complicado para resolver por aquí, porque es un tema de autorización en las peticiones a la API entre ti y un proveedor de servicios del que no tenemos documentación abierta (que encima tiene soporte). Y el problema no es que no llegue la petición. Es que no te la autorizan. De todos modos... has probado con `CURLOPT_USERPWD` a `$url0` y/o `$url1`?

Comment: No, no he usado `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, soy un poco nuevo en esto y estoy aprendiendo a la vez que desarrollo, me podrías direccionar en la forma de usarlo por favor?

Comment: El formato sería `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");`. Por supuesto, tendrías que cambiar `$username` y `$password`, pero no sé dónde lo tienes almacenado porque no se ve la estructura de tu `$my_user`. El funcionamiento en sí lo tienes en la documentación de PHP, https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Mira, ahora me acaban de enviar un token, corrígeme si no estoy en lo correcto... ahora que tengo un token, ya no necesito un usuario y contraseña cierto?... con lo anterior, me di cuenta que la primera vez, si lo probé así

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[SOLUCIONADO]***

Después de investigar muchísimo, di con un programa que te ayuda a testear API's previo a su uso y en la documentación de este, pude ver que mi método de conexión correcto era el de BEARER, a parte de que tuve que solicitar un nuevo endpoit para poder tener un nuevo token de acceso

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.hyperguest.io',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

Este código puede simplificarse un poco, haciéndolo de esta manera

```
$url = "https://api.hyperguest.io";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Espero a alguien le sirva mas adelante este código.

Gracias a todos los que comentaron.